# Getting started with REST between two SaaS apps?

Tags: web-services, saas

General form of the question : If you're planning to make 2 SaaS apps talk to each other, do most people try to make one of them initiate and control, or do they make (or buy) a 3rd party integration app?

I have ServiceNow Express, with a well-populated CMDB. I also have Confluence Hosted, which is new and empty. SNC Express does not lend itself to the kind of wiki-d, linked documentation I'd like about my environment. Thus, I'd like to have my Business Services, Applications, and Servers documented in Confluence, as Pages (I think). I don't want to have to export/import all my CMDB entries from SNC into Confluence, or at least not more than once.

I know how to code, but I don't do much of it, not more than simple bash or PoSH scripts. I have done very little with REST, and I'm really not sure how to get started. I know Confluence and SNC can both respond to REST requests, but where do those come from? In SNC Express, I could make a Business Rule (server-side scripting) that, when a new CMDB entry is created, to go ahead and send a REST creation method to Confluence to make a new Page. I don't see anything in Confluence to run server-side code if I wanted it to go the other way; am I missing something or do they not provide that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might as well put an answer in here, based on feedback I've gotten and what I've learned.

Most SaaS providers only offer a REST API to be consumed; few SaaS providers have built out the platform to allow them to make REST requests against other endpoints. ServiceNow has been the SaaS I'm most familiar with, and they're one of the few ones that have offered this, so that's why I was wondering where this feature is for other platforms.

Most people who need this will write or buy something to act as middleware/agent - which may itself be a SaaS service, or an on-prem program or set of scripts.